# Blender + three.js - Wrap image around object

Tags: three.js, blender

I am experimenting with exporting objects from blender and displaying them using three.js and all is going ok so far.  I have learnt enough about Blender to get me by as the objects I am using have just been downloaded from online.

What I am now trying to do is wrap an image around my object either within Blender or in three.js

Can anyone point me in the right direction for some reading on the preferred method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap an image around your model you will need to map it to your model in Blender. The file you then export from Blender will have both the geometry and material information you need for displaying it in three.js.

So, I used these two tutorials to learn how to UV map in Blender:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obB9T3jXlak (older but simpler)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2-FfB9kRmE (newer but more thorough)

Then use some coding like this: (taken from Jos Dirksen's Learning Three.js book)

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load('../assets/models/misc_chair01.js', function (geometry, mat) {
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mat[0]);

        mesh.scale.x = 15;
        mesh.scale.y = 15;
        mesh.scale.z = 15;

        scene.add(mesh);

    }, '../assets/models');
```

Make sure you have a copy of your jpeg image file in the same folder as your model.js file.